# How to implement some sort of Form Manager?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tform

I'm in the middle of a project with a number of child forms. Many of the forms may be open at once. I'd like to know if there's already something I can use to manage and keep track of these forms, much like the windows taskbar and/or task manager. If not, then what would be the best approach? I don't want to have to reinvent the wheel if this is already done.

**Description**

As mentioned above, this project has many forms which may be opened at once. I will also be implementing some visual list control (much like the taskbar or task manager) for user control of these forms (or in the user's case, the forms are called windows). The most ideal way to manage these would be to first capture each of these forms as they're created and keep record of them somewhere. Some forms need this behavior, and some forms do not. For example, modal forms will never need this handling.

I will be giving the user access to show, minimize, or close these forms, as well as some other future un-thought handling, like maybe a custom popup menu associated with one of these forms (but that's another subject). The point is, I need to build something to capture these forms and keep them in order.

This will also include some other user interaction with all the forms at once, as well as simple access to each one of them, similar to how Screen.Forms already works. For example, a command to minimize all forms (`FormManager.MinimizeAll`), to maximize the currently active form (`FormManager.ActiveForm.Maximize`), or with a particular form (`FormManager[3].Maximize`).

**Possible Options**

I understand there are a few far different approaches to accomplish similar results, and haven't started coding it yet because each of those approaches has a different starting point. The options are...

- Wrap Screen.Forms and other associated functionality from the Screen (which wouldn't allow too much of my desired flexibility)
- Every time I create a form, register it with this form manager (which is very flexible, but I have to make sure I always register each created form)
- Build a master form to register its self with the form manager and inherit everything from it (which is also very flexible, but in different ways, and much more complex)

The second option is sounding the most promising so far. But again, I don't want to start building it if there is already a solution for this. I'm pretty confident that I'm not the first person to do this. I don't know how to search for such a thing, I get nothing related to what I want on Google.

Comment: Define "manage and keep track of".  If you mean "know that a form exists, know it's caption and class name" then `Screen.Forms` or `Application.Forms` is what you want, as ain has said.

Comment: @WarrenP Question modified with many more details.

Comment: Good job Jerry. +1.  I see zero benefits to adding your own master class, and zero benefits in wrapping Screen.Forms. For your requirements, Screen.Forms is already perfect.  And you don't need to minimize all your forms, you can just do Application.Minimize and all forms get minimized.

Comment: @WarrenP Well all these forms are contained within the main form as their parent. It's much like a contained OS actually. I have tons of need to be able to do this type of control.

Comment: Actually, think of it as more of a dashboard, with a number of different panels (or forms) organized across the screen (or main form), and one of them larger than the others. With just 1 line of code, I could make it hide all the other forms and focus in on the larger one. All this again contained within the main form as their parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global variable `Screen` (in `Forms` unit) does some "tracking", ie

- [Screen.Forms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TScreen.Forms) list all currently open forms;
- [Screen.ActiveForm](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TScreen.ActiveForm) form which has input focus (see also [FocusedForm](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TScreen.FocusedForm));
- [Screen.OnActiveFormChange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TScreen.OnActiveFormChange) event;

Answer (score 3):

You could add each form to a TObjectList.  I wrote a component called FormStack, which allows you to add forms (even forms with the same name), retrieve, remove, etc.  To get a Task Manager like behavior, I think you'd just need to iterate the list to obtain form names . Hopefully you can use something here to shed some light on your idea..

Here's the code for FormStack.

```
unit uFormstack;

interface

uses
 Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Contnrs; 

type
  TFormstack = class(TComponent)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FormList: TObjectList;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); Override;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
    Procedure Add(InstanceClass: TComponentClass; Var Reference);
    Procedure RemoveLast;
    Procedure RemoveAll;
    Function FindForm(AComponentClass: TComponentClass): Boolean; 
    Function GetForm(AComponentClass: TComponentClass): TObject;
    Function GetByIndex(AIndex: Integer): TObject;
    Procedure RemoveByIndex(AIndex: Integer);
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

//{$R *.res}

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('FormStack', [TFormstack]);
end;

{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TFormStack
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

Constructor TFormStack.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
Begin
  Inherited Create(AOwner);
  FormList := TObjectList.Create;
  FormList.OwnsObjects := True;
End;

Destructor TFormStack.Destroy;
Begin
  FormList.Free;
  Inherited Destroy;
End;

Procedure TFormStack.Add(InstanceClass: TComponentClass; Var Reference);
Var
  Instance: TComponent;
Begin
  Instance := TComponent(InstanceClass.NewInstance);
  TComponent(Reference) := Instance;
  Instance.Create(Self); // Owner is FormList   <<-- blows up if datamodule in D2010
  FormList.Add(Instance);
  Instance.Tag := FormList.Count-1;
End;


Procedure TFormStack.RemoveAll;
Var
  I: Integer;
Begin
  For I := FormList.Count -1 downto 0 do  // last in first out
  begin
    Self.RemoveLast;
  End;
End;

// This removes the last form on the stack
Procedure TFormStack.RemoveLast;
Begin
  if FormList.Count > 0 then
     FormList.Remove(FormList.Items[FormList.Count-1]);
End;

Function TFormStack.FindForm(AComponentClass: TComponentClass): Boolean;
Var
  I: Integer;
Begin
  Result := False;
  For I := FormList.Count-1 downto 0 do
    If Formlist.Items[I].ClassType = AComponentClass then
      Result := True;
End;

Function TFormStack.GetForm(AComponentClass: TComponentClass): TObject;
Var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  For I := FormList.Count-1 downto 0 do
    If Formlist.Items[I].ClassType = AComponentClass then
      Result := FormList.Items[I];
end;

Function TFormStack.GetByIndex(AIndex: Integer): TObject;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  If FormList.Count-1 >= AIndex then
    Result := FormList.Items[AIndex];
end;

Procedure TFormStack.RemoveByIndex(AIndex: Integer);
begin
  If FormList.Count-1 >= AIndex then
    FormList.Remove(FormList.Items[AIndex]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: What good does having them in a list do you when it's already in the Screen.forms and Application.Forms lists?

Comment: @WarrenP being able to wrap the functionality and add your own functionality to the mix is the overall goal. No chance to peek at the above yet, but will try it out, thanks.

Comment: Eh, that's kinda how I intend to work, yes, but also combined with ain's answer. I don't need two different listings, I just need a good wrapper for what's already listed.

Comment: Jerry- your question would be more helpful to other people if you didn't treat StackOverflow as a kind of "help Jerry" only deal here. The hope is that you put some effort into asking the question with specific details that other people might search for and find later.  So what exactly you might "add" as your own functionality, and what exactly you're trying to do, are things we all care about around here, because otherwise we're really wasting a lot of time answering  a really useless (to everybody but you) question. PLEASE edit and improve this question.

Comment: @WarrenP I did mention, twice, the things which I would like this to do. I'll repeat: To have a central place where all forms are tracked where I can call commands like `FormManager.MinimizeAll` or `FormManager[1].BringToFront`. I think you're trying too hard to understand the question - it's actually a very simple subject.

Comment: And I wish I did know certain "keywords" to put in my question to make it "useful" but the fact is I don't know what's available out there. There's too many times I get 80% done with a project and realize that there is something already out there doing exactly what I was trying to build. So "form manager" and "taskbar" are the best ways of describing it, because I don't know what I should be calling it.

Comment: @Jerry adding a MinimizeAll and BringToFront to the above list manager is trivial.. I'll edit my answer and add the code..

Comment: No need to modify your answer, I get the gist clearly. I just added more detail to my question, since I had more time to sit down and think about it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to track this in code while the app is running?
Maybe you can do something with Screen.Forms?